# 2 SQL 2019 Servers with High Availability Linux with a shared Linux SQL Express 2019 Witness

Tags: sql-server, linux, high-availability

Is it possible to have two SQL Always on High Availability servers in datacentre A replicating to two servers in datacentre B with one Witness using Express with two availability groups (one for each server in Datacentre A/B) on Linux? I tried it but I'm having problems so i am not sure if it is what im doing or is it because it cannot be done and I will need two SQL Express Witness servers?

In addition, all servers are running on Linux Ubuntu

On the SQL Express I'm executing the command `ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [ag2] JOIN WITH (CLUSTER_TYPE = EXTERNAL)` and receiving the following error:

> Msg 47106, Level 16, State 3, Line 125 Cannot join availability group
>   'ag2'. Download configuration timeout. Please check primary
>   configuration, network connectivity and firewall setup, then retry the
>   operation. Msg 41158, Level 16, State 3, Line 125 Failed to join local
>   availability replica to availability group 'ag2'.  The operation
>   encountered SQL Server error 47106 and has been rolled back.  Check
>   the SQL Server error log for more details.  When the cause of the
>   error has been resolved, retry the ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP JOIN
>   command.

If I uninstall SQL Express and reinstall and then execute `ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [ag1] JOIN WITH (CLUSTER_TYPE = EXTERNAL)` it takes about 30-40 seconds and works. It is just when I trying to connect to [ag2].

All servers can ping each other.

Thanks